# Checking monoidal structure axiom on simple objects

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

If we consider a semisimple linear monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{D}$ another linear monoidal category, a linear functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and natural isomorphisms $J_{X,Y}: F(X)\otimes F(Y)\rightarrow F(X\otimes Y)$. If I want to show that the functor $(F,J_{X,Y})$ satisfies the monoidal structure axiom is it enough to just check it holds on the simple objects of $\mathcal{C}$ ? I feel like this should be true but I can't seem to show it because I would have to keep track of the isomorphisms from any object $Y$ into its direct sum of simple objects.

Moreover, if I consider $\mathcal{C}$ to be a category which is tensor and linearly generated by just one object (for example the category of graded vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) is a fully faithful functor uniquely defined by its value at the generator? (at least up to natural monoidal isomorphism?)

Comment: "linear monoidal" means that $\otimes$ is bilinear for a structure of a linear category on $\mathcal{C}$? And is $F$ supposed to be a linear functor?

Comment: Yes @PavelČoupek indeed I mean this. I have edited the question to include that $F$ is linear.

Comment: I would say that this should be true. Instead of carrying around isomorphisms of decompositions $Y \simeq Y_1 \oplus Y_2\oplus \dots \oplus Y_n$, one can carry around the morphisms $\iota_i: Y_i \rightarrow Y, \pi_i: Y \rightarrow Y_i$ that satisfy $\pi_j \iota_i=\delta_{ij}\mathrm{id}_{Y_i}$ and $\sum_i \iota_i \pi_i=\mathrm{id}_{Y}$.  Then given a natural transformation $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$ between additive functors, $\alpha_Y$ "decomposes diagonally", meaning $\alpha_{Y}=\alpha_{Y}\mathrm{id}_{F(Y)}=\sum_i\alpha_{Y}F(\iota_i)F(\pi_i)=\sum_iG(\iota_i)\alpha_{Y_i}F(\pi_i)$.

Comment: The last equality used naturality of $\alpha$. For bilinear functors as you have it works the same way (e.g. by treating them as addditive functors from $\mathcal{C}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{C}$).

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense!